# Converting ambiguous language to unambiguous

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I've been given a homework task to convert the following grammar to unambiguous.

```
A --> B
A --> ε
B --> B @ B
B --> STRING
B --> DOUBLE(STRING)
```

where A and B are non-terminals and STRING and DOUBLE are non-terminals.

I can derive that it is ambiguous given two different parse trees can be constructed for a string such as :

`STRING @ STRING @ DOUBLE(STRING)`.

So far, I've got:

```
A --> B | ε
B --> B @ DOUBLE(STRING)
B --> C
C --> C @ STRING | STRING | DOUBLE(STRING)
```

however it's not complete as the string such as:

STRING @ DOUBLE(STRING) @ STRING

cannot be made. How would I convert this grammar to unambiguous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing Joop's answer, you can introduce a new symbol `D` to eliminate the ambiguity around `B --> B @ B`:

```
A --> D
A --> ε
D --> D @ B
D --> B
B --> STRING
B --> DOUBLE(STRING)
```

With this change, only one tree is possible for any string in the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
STRING @ STRING @ STRING
```

could result from **A ⇒ B @(B @ B)** or **A ⇒ (B @ B) @ B**
because of

```
B --> B @ B
```

The solution is to introduce a new B-alike non-terminal and replace on of the occurrences with that nonterminal. This introduces an assymetry, you will find in many grammars.

The pleasure to figure out the rest I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks Joop. I've edited my post to what I think is what I could do best however I feel like my implementation of asymmetry is incorrect.

Comment: You have to mentally work out such a grammar yourself, as grammars are hard in the beginning. `B --> X (@ Y)*` would be more like the final desired result. Maybe drawing parse trees helps.

Comment: Sorry this whole concept of CFG is new to me but what does ' * ' mean and how would you apply that into a CFG?

Comment: That was intended as pseudo-code. The postfix operator ` *`  means 0 or more repetitions of the prior expression. Maybe you know the same thing as ` { @ Y }`.  `B -> C | B | @ C` . would be an unambiguous repetition.